How to list files in java for a different principal other than the one running the process
I need to be able to list files with nio and honor the ACLs assigned.
Issue is by default, nio checks permissions based on the user that is running the process but i need to be able to set the userprincipal.
example: my java is running with administrator user but i need to list files for userB.
Something like this
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.AclEntry;
import java.nio.file.attribute.AclEntryPermission;
import java.nio.file.attribute.AclEntryType;
import java.nio.file.attribute.AclFileAttributeView;
import java.nio.file.attribute.UserPrincipal;

public class ListFilesWithACL {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        try {
            listFolderContentWithACL("C:\\myDir", "administrator");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static void listFolderContentWithACL(String dir, String user) throws IOException {
        // Get UserPrincipal for a user called test
        UserPrincipal myUser = FileSystems.getDefault()
                .getUserPrincipalLookupService()
                .lookupPrincipalByName(user);
        
        Path path  = Paths.get(dir);
        
        if(doesACLAllowe(path, myUser, AclEntryPermission.LIST_DIRECTORY)) {
            try (DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
                for (Path p : directoryStream) {
                    
                    if(doesACLAllowe(p, myUser, AclEntryPermission.READ_DATA)) {
                        System.out.println(p.getFileName().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-----Done----");
    }
    
    private static boolean doesACLAllowe(Path p, UserPrincipal user, AclEntryPermission permission) throws IOException {
        AclFileAttributeView aclView = Files.getFileAttributeView(p, AclFileAttributeView.class);
        AclEntry acl = aclView.getAcl().stream()
                .filter(x -> x.principal().equals(user))
                .findFirst().orElse(null);

        if(acl != null && acl.type() == AclEntryType.DENY && acl.permissions().contains(permission)) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

but this requires a lot of loop which will affect the performance. and i think this will not cover groups.
